# Twitter trends based on dates and location

Tags: node.js, api, express, twitter

Is it possible to get the trends based on location as well as in between dates? I have achieved former straight through documents. The latter part is not in the params and I am certainly unsure about it.
Here is my code!

```
  router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  let city = req.body.location;
  let from = req.body.from;
  let to = req.body.to;


  let url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22" + encodeURI(city) + "%22&format=json";
  /*Using Twit library*/
  request(url, function (err, response, body) {
    var woeidData = JSON.parse(body);
    var woeid = woeidData.query.results.place[0].woeid;
    var tweets = [];
    var T = new Twit({
      consumer_key: "**",
      consumer_secret: "**",
      access_token: "**",
      access_token_secret: "**",
      timeout_ms: 60 * 1000,
    });
    T.get('trends/place', {
      id: woeid ,
      //q:'since 2011-07-11'
    }, function (err, data, response) {
      var converted = JSON.stringify(data);
      objects = JSON.parse(converted);

      tweets = objects[0].trends;
      //console.log(tweets[0]);
      for (let i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
        console.log("tweet is about" + tweets[i]);
      }
      //{tweetsData : tweets,data:true}
      res.render('index');
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  [The trends documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/trends/trends-for-location/overview) shows that you can only query using location.

If you want historic data, you will need to [build a time-machine](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-travel), sorry.

Comment: Or I can use premium API, sorry!

Comment: Haha! You didn't mention that in your original post.